# Not Able to Logout from Login WebView (ADLoginView)

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

In `React-Native` Application I have implemented Microsoft's AD Login Functionality by using [react-native-azure-ad@0.2.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-ad)".

Getting trouble while Logout from Microsoft's Account. When I trigger Logout First LoginView.js get rendered and then ADLoginView(WebView) redirects to Microsofts Login Page where upon entering new user id the app is taking me back to old logged out user login. [Basically previous users token is stored and I am not able to clear that]

See The below ScreenShot

[image: Microsoft's login page]

```js
/ ** Login.js **/

let needLogout 

export default class Login extends Component { 
 
 constructor(){
  super()
 
  this.state = {
   logout : false
  }

  new ReactNativeAD({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          authority_host: 'https://login.windows.net/common',
          redirect_uri: 'http://xxz.myappdomain.biz',
          resources: [
            'https://graph.microsoft.com',
          ]
    })

        context = ReactNativeAD.getContext(CLIENT_ID)
 }
 
 componentDidMount(){
  needLogout = () => this.needLogoutSetFalse()
  EventBus.addEventListener("Logout", needLogout);
 }

 render(){
         return(
   <ADLoginView
             context={context}
             onSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)}
             hideAfterLogin = {true}
             needLogout = {this.state.logout}         
          />)                  
 }

 onLoginSuccess(credentials){
  //Call The graph API and Navigate to Next view
 }

 needLogoutSetFalse(){
      EventBus.removeEventListener("Logout", needLogout)
      ReactNativeAD.removeContext(CLIENT_ID)
   
   // By Setting needLogout true Webview will redirect to  n .  Microsoft’s official login page.
       this.setState({logout: true})
   }

}


/** Logout.js **/

 onClickLogOut(){
  
     // Will Clear Entire Async Storage.

     userInfo.removeUser().then(()=>{
   // Will Navigate to Login Page 
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
   
   // Invoke the needLogoutSetFalse method from Login.js.
               EventBus.dispatch("Logout")
               Toast.show('Log out successful')
        })
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works check the below link,
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad/issues/21#issuecomment-322645856